# TeXstudio is exceptionally slow when using find

Tags: texstudio

TeXstudio is unresponsive on startup, when opening new files and when using the find function (ctrl+f). Sometimes it can get upwards of 1 minute after hitting ctrl+f for it to respond.
However this is only the first time using ctrl+f on a file, on subsequent times it works instantly.

Meanwhile compiling and generally most other functions work normally.

I am using TeXstudio version 4.7.2 on Windows 11 (v22H2).
I have tried uninstalling (removing local files and restarting) and reinstalling but it didn't work.

Comment: Including your operating system might be helpful. Also does this happen with all files or just certain files?

Comment: It happens with all files. (I also edited the question to include my OS)

Comment: Does the problem persist if you temporarily rename the config folder before opening texstudio? On mac the folder is at `~/.config/texstudio`, no idea where it would be on windows.

Comment: That fixes the problem! But I still can't pinpoint exactly where the problem is with the old config.

Comment: Can you open the file `texstudio.ini` inside the config folder? Check if the entry `Search\Find%20History=` is very long. This could maybe cause some delay when textudio loads the search history. Or does any other entry stand out as very long?

Comment: That's it, there was an extremely long entry with bugged out characters; once I deleted it the problem was resolved! Thank you!
I guess you can post it as an answer.

Comment: Glad this solved the problem! I'll write something up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Texstudio keeps a list of the previously searched phrases in its config file. If the list gets too long (or otherwise hard to parse), opening the search can take a while.

#### How to diagnose:

As a quick test, rename the config folder before opening texstudio. On mac the folder is located at `~/.config/texstudio`.

If this is indeed the source of the problem, the search should now open immediately.

#### How to fix:

To fix this problem, open the `texstudio.ini` file in the config folder and search for the `Search\Find%20History=` and clean up all entries in the find history you don't need.

This should speed up the search for some time. If it becomes slow again, repeat the process.